# Calling external process from Groovy/Java gives unexpected result

Tags: java, groovy, process, external

From Groovy/Java I try to execute following command: `cmd /c echo mytext`.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset

println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()) //returns windows-1250
//in console chcp returns 852

def arg = "/c echo mytext"
def pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", arg)
def proc = pb.start()

def stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(), "CP852"))
def stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream(), "CP852"))

def line = null
println("Here is the standard output of: cmd " + arg)
while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    println(line)
}

println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):")
while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    println(line)
}
```

Groovy: 2.4.21, 3.0.9

Java: zulu11.50.19-ca-fx-jdk11.0.12-win_x64

The result is `mytext"` (including ending double quote). I cannot figure out why the double qoute is there. Can anybody help to explain me why is it there?

Thank you.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "echo", "mytext")` should help.

Comment: @daggett Thank you, it works. So simple and it did not occur me. And I am still currious about a cause of the double qoute. Do you know why it is there?

Comment: "And I am still currious about a cause of the double qoute. Do you know why it is there?" - In the code `ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "echo", "mytext")` you could replace the double quotes with single quotes and have the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short: `ProcessBuilder` will wrap each argument that contains spaces with double quotes

so, `ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c echo mytext")` actually runs `cmd "/c echo mytext"`

try this command in command prompt:

```
c:\> cmd "/c echo mytext"
mytext"
```

^^^ that's exactly what you have in your result

question why cmd interprets arguments this way must be addressed to microsoft - maybe there is a logical explanation

however `echo` is not parsing arguments and outputs argument line as is

```
c:\> echo "my text"
"my text"

c:\> echo my text
my text
```

means that correct answer for `echo my text`: `ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "echo my text")`

---

let me suggest a groovy variant for your code:

```
def out = {s-> print(s)} as Appendable
def err = {s-> print(s)} as Appendable

def command = ['cmd', '/c', 'echo my text']
def proc = command.execute()

proc.waitForProcessOutput(out,err)
```